# error when installing QSWAT in QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, qswat

I want to use QSWAT in the QGIS environment but after downloading and installing the SWATeditor and QSWAT I get two errors:

1)First: *Couldn't load plugin MetaSearch due an error when calling its classFactory() method*

2)Second: *Couldn't load plugin QSWAT due an error when calling its classFactory() method*

And then as expected in the plugin window it tells me the plugin is broken.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I´m, also, facing problems to install the QSWAT Plugin. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wtXL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wtXL.png)

Comment: Try (re)installing things in the order in the documentation.This worked for me.

Comment: I have some problem too after install swat editor and QSWAT seems success, but after QGIS was begin, the plugin doesn't showed. Is QGIS version 2.8 dosen't compatible for QSWAT version 1.9?

Answer (score 3):

[QSWAT](http://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/) isn't in the QGIS plugin repository, and is Windows-only.

If you've followed [the documentation](http://swat.tamu.edu/media/115523/qswat-manual_v14.pdf) and are still having problems, you might want to ask on the [google user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US#!forum/qswat).

Comment: New version at https://swat.tamu.edu/software/plus/